# Checking if parent state promise has returned value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Using `AngularJS` and `ui-router` to create states and I have a parent and child state.

```
    .state('portfolio', {
        url: '/portfolio',
        templateUrl: 'app/templates/portfolio/portfolio.tpl.htm',
        controller: 'portfolioCtrl',
        controllerAs: '$ctrl'
    })
    .state('portfolio.patent', {
        url: '/:patentId',
        views:{
            "": {
                controller: 'caseOverviewCtrl',
                controllerAs: '$ctrl',
                templateUrl: 'app/templates/patent/case-overview.tpl.htm',
            },
            //FURTHER SIBLING VIEWS
       }
     })
```

In `portfolio` in the controller I make a request, await the promise and then display the data to the user in a table. If the user selects an item from the table, it displays further information in a child state `portfolio.patent`, passing an id value to `$stateParams`, which I then use to make the $http call to fetch more information.

If I refresh the page, the child state is displaying before the parent state, as the parent state $http request takes longer to resolve as there is a lot more data to fetch. I've tried to check from the child state the value of `portfolioLoaded` but it only checks it once.

## Question

How do I check the parent state promise has resolved, before displaying the child state to the user?

I see using `ng-show` in the `portfolio.patent' view to check the controller whether the parent promise has been resolved.

#### PORTFOLIO CONTROLLER

```
var promise = patentsRestService.fetchAllPatents();
promise.then(
    function(response){
        var patents = response;
        $scope.portfolioLoaded = true;
    }
)
```

#### PORTFOLIO.PATENT CONTROLLER

```
function init() {
    if($scope.$parent.portfolioLoaded) {
        $scope.parentLoaded = true;
    }
}
```

#### PATENT VIEW

```
<div data-ng-show="$ctrl.portfolioLoaded" class="animate-show">
   //CONTENT
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the promise in the parent controller:

```
$scope.promise = patentsRestService.fetchAllPatents();
$scope.promise.then(
    function(response){
        var patents = response;
        $scope.portfolioLoaded = true;
    }
)
```

Use the promise in the child controller:

```
function init() {
    $scope.$parent.promise.then(function() {
        $scope.parentLoaded = true;
    });
}
```

This will properly delay the setting.

Answer (score 0):

Move parent state's call into `resolve`:

```
.state('portfolio', {
    url: '/portfolio',
    templateUrl: 'app/templates/portfolio/portfolio.tpl.htm',
    controller: 'portfolioCtrl',
    controllerAs: '$ctrl',
    resolve: {
        patentData: function(patentsRestService){
            return patentsRestService.fetchAllPatents()
        }
    }
})
```

It will always be resolved before child state loads

Read more: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve

Comment: This is what I did but this issue was the load times, the state holds until it's resolved. Impact user experience